# How to Auto download the images to local from img tag?

Tags: php, html, image

I have this:

```
<img id ="saveimage" src="image.php<?php echo $finalRequest; ?>" alt="Barcode Image" />
```

How to achieve that make auto download the image to local from this img tag?
Thanks!!

Comment: You want to download it when clicked? Or auto-download upon visiting the page?

Answer (score -2):

Put `<a>`  tag on the image and point it to the folder where it is located, then add a .htaccess to force download the file, google how to do it via .htaccess..